# Can't get middle text in list aligned correctly

Tags: css, list, react-native, alignment

I am trying to make like a payout summary. Left is date, middle part is occurrence and right is sum. As you can see from the screenshot, the left and right is properly aligned, but the middle part, in my language called "hendelse", does not align correctly:

[image]

Code follows here;

```
const Betalinger = [
{
    date:'16.04.2020',
    occurrence:'Utbetaling',
    sum: 11020,
},
{
    date:'15.03.2020',
    occurrence:'Utbetaling',
    sum: 8265,
},
{
    date:'14.02.2020',
    occurrence:'Utbetaling',
    sum: 8265,
},
{
    date:'14.01.2020',
    occurrence:'Utbetaling',
    sum: 8265,
},
{
    date:'14.12.2019',
    occurrence:'Utbetaling',
    sum: 8200,
},



];
```

export default function Utbetaling() {

```
return(
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

        <View style = {styles.titleHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Dato</Text>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Hendelse</Text>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Beløp</Text>
        </View>

        <ScrollView>
            {Betalinger.map((item, index) => (
                <View  key = {index} style={styles.listItems}>
                    <Text style={styles.ItemText}>{item.date}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.ItemText}>{item.occurrence + "     "}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.ItemText}>{item.sum + " kr"}</Text>
                </View>

            ))}
        </ScrollView>

            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.LinkContainer} onPress={() => Linking.openURL("https://lanekassen.no/nb-NO/verktoy-og-frister/Frister-i-Lanekassen/utbetaling-av-utdanningsstotte/") }>
                <FontAwesome key ={0} name ={'arrow-circle-right'} size={30} color={'#4d264f'} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>


    </SafeAreaView>
);
```

And CCS:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
},
titleHeader: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: '#4d264f',
    height: "15%",
    width: "100%",
    bottom: 10,
},
titleText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 16,
},
listItems: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    marginBottom: 10,
},
ItemText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    marginBottom: 10,
},
LinkContainer: {
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
},
```

Any tips are highly welcome :))

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the dates are wider than the other two texts.
Can you try giving every `ItemText` the same fixed width, so that `justifyContent: "space-around"` can position them equal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following styles :

```
listItems: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    marginBottom: 10,
    flex: 1,
},
ItemText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    marginBottom: 10,
    flex: 1/3,
    textAlign: 'center'
},
```

and result will be like this :
[image]